# Instance of Rails model only creatable through console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, rails-console

I've been following the tutorial on creating a Rails blog (http://www.roberthuberdeau.com/articles/4-How-to-create-a-blog-in-Ruby-on-Rails-3) and have basically got all the way to the end.

However, after all the migrations I'm now struggling. Whenever I complete the form I previously used to create articles, I can't see them on the index page. I've dug around and believe the root of the error is that I'm not saving any articles when I press 'create article'.

To test this, I created an article using the console and this is appearing as it should so I think the problem lies somewhere between the form that creates articles and the controller (though am happy to be corrected on this).

Whenever I try the following appears in the logs:

```
Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-01 21:12:58 +0100
Processing by ArticlesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XLeHm+4Tgd6n9vt4RxAQ5YVTbWTi+UnqkmBso9Iuo+4=", "article"=>{"title"=>"I rule", "body"=>"Change teams.", "tag_names"=>"kill", "published"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Article"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles_users"."user_id" = 1 AND "roles"."name" = 'Admin' LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles_users"."user_id" = 1 AND "roles"."name" = 'Moderator' LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles_users"."user_id" = 1 AND "roles"."name" = 'Member' LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

With the database schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130401171646) do

  create_table "articles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at",                    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                    :null => false
    t.integer  "user_id",                       :null => false
    t.boolean  "published",  :default => false
  end

  create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "roles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "roles_users", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "role_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "taggings", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "tags", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

end
```

Articles controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]
  # GET /articles
  # GET /articles.xml
  def index
    @articles = Article.published.page(params[:page]).per(5).ordered

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @articles }
    end
  end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.xml
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new(:article=>@article)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @article }
    end
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  # GET /articles/new.xml
  def new
    @article = Article.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @article }
    end
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :edit, @article
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.xml
  def create
    authorize! :create, @article
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])
    @article.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 'Article was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @article, :status => :created, :location => @article }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @article.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /articles/1
  # PUT /articles/1.xml
  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :update, @article
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
        format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 'Article was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @article.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /articles/1
  # DELETE /articles/1.xml
  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :destroy, @article
    @article.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(articles_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end


end
```

Articles model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :title, :tag_names
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
  validates_presence_of :title, :body
  validates_uniqueness_of :title
  attr_writer :tag_names
  after_save :assign_tags
  validates_numericality_of :user_id  
  belongs_to :user
  scope :published, lambda {{:conditions => ['published = ?', true]}}
  scope :ordered, lambda {{:order => "Created_at DESC" }}
  def tag_names
    @tag_names || tags.map(&:name).join(' ')
  end

  private

  def assign_tags
    if @tag_names
      self.tags = @tag_names.split(/\,/).map do |name|
        Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And the form partial used to create the article:

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag_names, "Tags" %>  
    <%= f.text_field :tag_names %>  
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= check_box("article", "published" ) %>
    <%= "Publish article" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any help you can give me on this would be greatly appreciated.

By request:

Ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    if user.role? :Admin
      can :manage, :all
      can :publish, Article
    elsif user.role? :Moderator
      can :read, [Article, Comment]
      can [:edit, :update], Comment
    elsif user.role? :Member
       can :read, :all
       can :create, [Article, Comment]
       can [:edit, :update], Comment
    end
  end
end
```

p.s. the only other error I can see (and I don't know if it's relevant or a different issue entirely) is that when trying to view an article (show.html.erb) I receive the following error:

```
Processing by ArticlesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Article Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 44ms

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: article):
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:18:in `new'
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:18:in `show'
```

Comment: what does this line do? `authorize! :create, @article`

Comment: @Zippie My (perhaps flawed) understanding is that this only allows authorized users to perform this action? A little on where I got that idea from: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing there's a problem with the `authorize! :create, @article` line in the `ArticleController.create`. At the point that that executes, `@article` isn't created yet.

Judging by the CanCan source, I think the following might do what you want:

```
def create
   authorize! :create, Article
   @article = Article.new(params[:article])
   @article.user_id = current_user.id
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly - I've just made the change you suggested and I'm afraid it hasn't worked, I'll have a look through the CanCan docs now and see where I might be going wrong.

Comment: Ok. I think another approach that's more likely to work is to just move the `authorize! :create, @article` line after `@article.user_id = current_user.id`. That way it has an instance of the model to authorize.

Comment: Well I changed the order so that it went:
`@article = Article.new(params[:article])`
`@article.user_id = current_user.id`
`authorize! :create, @article`

but that doesn't work either. Nightmare.

(looks like we were thinking the same thing!)

Comment: No error or anything? The article just never shows up on the index page?

Comment: Also, does it work if you remove the `authorize!` call entirely?

Comment: No error, it's just not saving the article (when I check all the articles in console I can see the only one there is the one I created using console). When I remove the authorize! call it does work as it should.

Comment: Another possible clue added at the bottom of the question - have found another error which may or may not be linked to this one.

Comment: Ok, I think that for whatever reason, `authorize!` is sending you back to the front page because you don't have permission to `:create`. Are you sure you're logged in as a `Member`? It looks like they're the only ones allowed to `:create` an article. And I think you can tackle that other error by adding `attr_accessible :article, :article_id` to your `Comment` model.

Comment: I only have one user at the moment and they are marked as admin - would a `:manage, :all` not allow the user to create articles?

Either way, I have now added `can :create, [Article, Comment]` to the Admin model and it still won't create.

The hint on the other error has fixed it - now the individual articles are showing :)

Comment: You're right, `:manage` includes other permissions. You could try a few debugging checks, adding `p can?(:create, Article)`, `p current_user`, and `p current_user.role?(:Admin)` in place of `authorize!` and then looking for their output in the console/log.

Comment: Finally got it solved using those hints - the current_user was registered as an admin but I'd set the admin ID incorrectly - thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The article is not being created because of this.

`authorize! :create, @article`

You will have to show us your ability model, ability.rb.

You might also want to try the obvious. `bundle install` and restart the server.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the controller as per below and it hasn't worked, same with `bundle install` and restarting.

Ability model going in question...

Comment: Have edited the question again as there's another error that may or may not be causing/influencing this problem.